# How to download Azure Function (Python) .zip file?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

The docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#download-your-function-app-files) (from 2018) say to click `Download app content` from the Portal to retrieve a .zip file of your Azure Function.

**However, this option is grayed out for my Python function:**

[image]

The doc goes on to provide an alternative method for retrieving a .zip file using REST API with the following url `https://<function_app>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/`.

Unfortunately, this downloads a `download.zip` file containing only the `hosts.json` file rather than the Function code and associated files.

[image]

So, how do I download my Python Function as a .zip file from either Azure Portal, REST API or the scm backend?

**EDIT 1:**
Trying the two proposed solutions so far yield no results either.

- `AzureWebJobsStorage`: No `scm-deployments` container available.
  [image]
- FTPS option: No .zip file available. Only the `host.json` file.
  [image]

Comment: How do you deploy your Function to the App? Dumb Q but are you sure you have deployed the Function?!

Comment: Function deployed from local machine using [Azure Function Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash). Yes :) Function has been deployed several times over several months now and works as intended. Just can't seem to locate the .zip file anywhere!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally! Figured this out.

**To download the .zip file of a deployed Python Azure Function:**

- Go to `https://<function-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/data/SitePackages/`
- The body will look something like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "20210507210231.zip",
        "size": 22920602,
        "mtime": "2021-05-07T21:03:30.9505229+00:00",
        "crtime": "2021-05-07T21:03:30.9505229+00:00",
        "mime": "application/x-zip-compressed",
        "href": "https://<function-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/data/SitePackages/20210507210231.zip",
        "path": "/home/data/SitePackages/20210507210231.zip"
    },
    {
        "name": "20210512182244.zip",
        "size": 91280954,
        "mtime": "2021-05-12T18:22:46.4017597+00:00",
        "crtime": "2021-05-12T18:22:46.4017597+00:00",
        "mime": "application/x-zip-compressed",
        "href": "https://<function-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/data/SitePackages/20210512182244.zip",
        "path": "/home/data/SitePackages/20210512182244.zip"
    },
    {
        "name": "20210520163007.zip",
        "size": 22248931,
        "mtime": "2021-05-20T16:31:13.4771898+00:00",
        "crtime": "2021-05-20T16:31:13.4771898+00:00",
        "mime": "application/x-zip-compressed",
        "href": "https://<function-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/data/SitePackages/20210520163007.zip",
        "path": "/home/data/SitePackages/20210520163007.zip"
    },
    {
        "name": "packagename.txt",
        "size": 18,
        "mtime": "2021-05-20T16:31:20.8453653+00:00",
        "crtime": "2021-05-20T16:31:20.8453653+00:00",
        "mime": "text/plain",
        "href": "https://<function-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/data/SitePackages/packagename.txt",
        "path": "/home/data/SitePackages/packagename.txt"
    },
    {
        "name": "packagepath.txt",
        "size": 23,
        "mtime": "2021-05-12T18:22:46.5567703+00:00",
        "crtime": "2021-05-12T18:22:46.5567703+00:00",
        "mime": "text/plain",
        "href": "https://<function-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/data/SitePackages/packagepath.txt",
        "path": "/home/data/SitePackages/packagepath.txt"
    }
]
```

- Go to the `href` URL shown with the latest `mtime` to download the file
- **Notice:** The latest timestamp is lower in the list (at least for me)

Its documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/recover-python-functions?tabs=vscode#view-project-files)

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

From your comment, you say your function app only have 'host.json' file. So you didn't deploy the azure function before? Or you deploy failed? Ftps(for premium plan and app service plan) or copy the files one by one is to get the content of the zip file. And get zip file from the 'scm-releases' container in blob storage should be a right way.

This is the [structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#folder-structure) of a python azure function. So just get all of the files can get the content of zip files. If you didn't find anything when check it on portal, I think maybe you deploy failed or never deploy the function app before? The zip file should generate in 'scm-releases' container if you deploy successful before.

**Original Answer:**

It seems 'Download app content' button of python azure function is unavailable now. The documentation you provided was updated on August 12, 2018, but the support of azure function for python started on [August 18, 2019](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-general-availability-of-python-support-in-azure-functions/), so the documentation of 'Download function app files' may not be applicable. I think maybe you can submit a ticket to the official that this button is not available.

You can use ftp to get app content, but only for premium plan and app service plan:

[image]

If you are based on the consumption plan, you need to click in each trigger and copy the code.

[image]

And the files outside the trigger is in this place:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, FTPS endpoint (`ftp://<azure-specifics>.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot/`) does not provide a .zip file of the deployment. Only the `host.json` file same as if I were using `https://<function_app>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/`.

Comment: This Function is in production, working, has been deployed many times using Azure Function Core Tools (`func azure functionapp publish <function-name>`). Uses a premium app service plan (`P2V2`). I see the individual files just fine in Portal (`Function App/Functions/Code+Test`). I want to retrieve the deployed .zip file. It seems this is not possible. As I've already stated, FTPS shows only the `host.json` and `AzureWebJobsStorage` has no `scm` container.

Comment: @ericOnline Is your function app based on a consumption plan? If yes, then you will be unable to use ftp to get the content.

Comment: No. Function uses Premium P2V2 plan.

Comment: At this point, I still have no valid way to download the .zip file for a Python Azure Function. Any further ideas?

Comment: Any further ideas here?

Comment: @ericOnline I think there is no good ideas... If there is no zip files, maybe you can click and copy the files one by one as I mentioned in the original answer.

Comment: @ericOnline Do you know continuous deployment?

Comment: Its quite baffling how the deployed .zip file is no where to be found in Azure. Why this is, I have no idea. I was able to reverse engineer what the .zip folder structure *should be* but only after long analysis (`.venv/Lib/site_packages` must be translated to `.python_packages/lib/site_packages` for a deployment to be successful). Would have been much easier to just download a deployed .zip file and look at its directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the Function's storage account then just download from `scm-releases` container.

You can find the account connection string in `AzureWebJobsStorage` parameter under Configuration in portal (App Settings).

[image]

Comment: The two containers you show `function-app-archive` and `scm-releases` are not present in any of the Function internal storage accounts (those tied to `AzureWebJobsStorage`). I only see `azure-webjobs-hosts` and `azure-webjobs-secrets`.

Comment: Any further ideas here?